# protected videos are not working on Ubuntu 14.04 on TVNZ on Demand

Tags: video, flash, proprietary, video-streaming

I installed Ubuntu on my wife's computer without her permission and she is very impressed, except that she can not watch: http://tvnz.co.nz/video - TVNZ on Demand... ohhhh I know what you are thinking... why watch that trash when there is so much good stuff out there - but apparently without bing bang theory her life is incomplete... Can you please help me make it work? Any ideas at all? THANK YOU ( we are in NZ and have flash player installed, etc...)
PS if you know an alternative legal way to watch (STUPID) Bing Bang Theory then I am all for it!

Answer (score 0):

I expect there is some proprietary Digital Rights Management stuff required to view their shows similar to what Netflix here in the U.S. uses. We have to run a browser and Microsoft's "Silverlight" under wine to make Netflix work. It seems Netflixs is frightfully worried that the open source crowd will find a way to copy their material if they make it available to open source software.

If you have to have this show, `http://www.cbs.com/shows/big_bang_theory/` but you might need to VPN into the U.S. market to use it. I used `airvpn.org` to watch the London Olympics straight off the BBC here in Califonia. A good VPN service is also valuable for privacy protection.

Comment: THANK YOU Marc for your answer.  I cant vote you up, but I would if I could ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mjblenner/ppa-hal
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hal
```

And then restart - that seemed to get Firefox working for me with TVNZ on 14.04